# Secure GPS location in Android App

Tags: android, gps

How to ensure secured `GPS location in Android app`. There are so many "Fake GPS" applications lying around on the internet. I have to build an application which uses the `GPS` location of the user. Is there any way I can ensure that the GPS location is never wrong (or tampered/fake)? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your minimum sdk level is >= 18, you can use `isFromMockProvider()` method of the `Location` object to check.

Hope this helps.